# Microsoft Edge can not set data attribute on SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Just run into something I did not expect. Testing a site in IE Edge, I get an error in the console:

*Unable to set property 'shape' of undefined or null reference*

After debugging for a while it seems that Microsoft Edge can not set a data attribute on an SVG element using dataset. I made a reduced test case:

https://codepen.io/freemagee/pen/YQRowd

There is a single SVG on that Codepen, which I then try to add some data attributes to it using dataset. When I view that codepen in Microsoft Edge I get the console error.

**Codepen snippets**

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <rect id="square" width="50" height="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

JS

```
function setSvgData() {
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

  svg.dataset.shape = 'square';
  svg.dataset.emotion = 'gloomy';
}

setSvgData();
```

Having read up on [SVGElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/dataset) I am unsure what to do now to resolve this. I would like to avoid having to rewrite all my dataset code with setAttribute if possible.

Anyone experienced this or know how to resolve it?

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/15885483-support-dataset-and-data-attributes-on-svg-element

Comment: Thanks Robert. Shame it seems to be a bit of a deadend. I tried one of the polyfills on https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#dataset-property-for-use-with-custom-data--attributes with no effect atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue for it with the status of *'Fixed, Not yet flighted'* here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8489259/

In the meantime, and for backwards compatibility, using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` instead of `dataset` seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a basic feature test for those that run across this in the future.

https://codepen.io/freemagee/pen/QgoNJz

Basically a SVG is dynamically created and the dataset is manipulated in a try/catch.

```
var hasSvgDatasetSupport = supportSvgDataset();

function supportSvgDataset() {
  var doesSupport = true;
  var testSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

  try {
    testSvg.dataset.shape = 'vector';
  } catch (error) {
    doesSupport = false;
  }

  return doesSupport;
}

// Example usage

var el = document.getElementById('shape');

if (hasSvgDatasetSupport) {
  el.dataset.mood = 'happy';
} else {
  el.setAttribute('data-mood', 'unhappy');
}
```

I am not smart enough to do a proper polyfill, but this took a site that failed in Microsoft Edge to fully working.

Comment: Your solution works, but why not just always use setAttribute, which works in all browsers? Using dataset has no immediate advantage other than syntax.

Comment: @Ferdy, you are right. The whole situation could be mitigated by using setAttribute. But this scenario came out in testing and dataset was used primarily in that project.